# Can I search for multiple words using RedGate's SQL Search?

Tags: redgate, sql-search

I want to do this:

[image]

I know I can search for an exact match for one word but I want to be able to search for multiple words in the same object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet.

We are currently prioritizing the next set of work on SQL Search.

Please vote or comment on our UserVoice forum for updates on this specific feature request:
https://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/101149-sql-search/suggestions/1493729-allow-or-and-not-searches

Thanks!